# How to set the default application to open folders?

Tags: ubuntu, files, desktop, mime-types, visual-studio-code

I'm really stuck;
I want to add `Open with vs code` to the folders context menu following the same approach as for files by means of the so-called MIME; editing the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` allows me to change default applications for different file extensions.

My preferred default application is VS Code; I found `inode/directory` is the file type for a directory in MIME, so I added this line `inode/directory=code-insiders.desktop` to the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` in [Default Applications] field but `Open with vs code` doesn't show as I right-click on folders.

I can confirm what I did makes sense by showing the output of this command `gio mime inode/directory`:

```
Default application for “inode/directory”: code-insiders.desktop
Registered applications:
    code-insiders.desktop
    org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
    org.gnome.baobab.desktop
Recommended applications:
    code-insiders.desktop
    org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
    org.gnome.baobab.desktop
```

Similarly, the output of `gio mime text/plain` by which the corresponding files context menu appears `Open with vs` option is

```
Default application for “text/plain”: code-insiders.desktop
Registered applications:
    code-insiders.desktop
    libreoffice-writer.desktop
    org.gnome.gedit.desktop
    vim.desktop
Recommended applications:
    code-insiders.desktop
    libreoffice-writer.desktop
    org.gnome.gedit.desktop
    vim.desktop
```

The default application for opening text files by right-clicking shows `Open with vs` but not the case for folders.

Comment: Any solutions already for this? BTW at the moment all folders (and all files recourseivly are opened in VLC-media player). Some misconfiguration.

Comment: Just an note - there must be some entry for that, since after installing Konqueror, all directories open in that. Maybe inspecting Konqueror's install scripts would reveal how that's done?

Comment: Everything defaults to Konequeror for me too and I'm running Gnome.  This is unbearable.  How do we fix this???